# Is it possible to create a Blender animation with electronics components?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender. I wish to create electronics circuits like connecting a resistor to a bulb with a switch and make it work as if when the switch is On the light is On and if the switch is Off the light turns off. Can that be made?
P.S. I'm well aware of coding, so I'm a coder in various coding languages thus if the case is to code I'm in!
Thanks much for any support

Comment: Yup,it is entirely possible. You have to use animation keyframes and things like emmision and position keyframing. But first create all the models and you don't have to code anything because blender animation is very flexible.

Comment: thanks Raj, do you know about a simple demo that can illustrate this activity? I really need something very simple - an illustration of a basic circuit that includes a lamp, a switch, a resistor and a DC power-supply. That's all.

Comment: I cant seem to find any tutorial where the exact thing is done but i suggest watching these two tutorials. The first is how to create things like circuit board in blender-https://youtu.be/9iO-7RbDSw8 And second one is the basics of animation in blender-https://youtu.be/zp6kCe5Kmf4 .Hope it helps

Comment: Found something you might find interesting- https://youtu.be/WxKY4u-fgDA and https://youtu.be/FDpS27chhak

Comment: These are interesting videos. I'm trying to work this out for my needs. Thanks again Raj.